# In C++, is checking `this == nullptr` inside member functions an acceptable pattern?

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I have seen C++ classes that check the `this` pointer to make sure it is not `nullptr` before using a field.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm talking about:

```
#include <iostream>

class object
{
public:
    void set(int v)
    {
        if(this == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }
        value_ = v;
    }

    int get() const
    {
        if(this == nullptr)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return value_;
    }

private:
    int value_ = -1;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    object *o = nullptr;

    o->set(5);
    std::cout << "nullptr: value = " << o->get() << "\n";

    o = new object;

    o->set(5);
    std::cout << "allocated: value = " << o->get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

As we can see, when we run this program, it works (it doesn't crash) even though the first two calls (`o->set()` and `o->get()`) use a `nullptr`.

Still, I think such tests are okay to verify in a debug version, but not a final version of the class. i.e. it should always be the responsibility of the user of an object to verify that the object exists before calling functions on it. Just like you would have to do if you had a public field and tried to access it. So in the above, we should have:

```
    if(o != nullptr)
    {
        o->set(5);
        std::cout << "nullptr: value = " << o->get() << "\n";
    }
```

What I'd like to find out is a clear statement about such usage of the `this` pointer within member functions and why it shouldn't be used.

Comment: I don't think it's an acceptable pattern.  It won't even work with virtual functions.

Comment: `this` **cannot** be `nullptr`.  The compiler knows that it cannot be nullptr.  Checking for nullptr is a no-op.  Calling methods on a nullptr ptr is well into **undefined behavior** land — so any observed behavior is allowed.

Comment: Example of above: https://godbolt.org/z/Px5zb3f5P

Comment: *I have seen C++ classes that check the this pointer to make sure it is not nullptr* --  Where have you seen this?  As mentioned, the compiler knows it's nonsense checking `this` for `nullptr`, thus when the compiler's optimizer sees it, whole swaths of code that depends on the nonsense check can be removed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie One example that I know of: https://github.com/dblock/msiext/blob/master/externals/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/mfc42/afxwin2.inl#L17

Comment: @Evg This line of code is *older* than C++98. Back then people didn't know that `this` can't be null and just wanted to be "on the safe side".

Comment: @j6t I doubt they didn't know that.

Comment: It is UB by the standard, but I think MSVC does (did?) permit calling member function on a null pointer like this. GCC and Clang have `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` to permit it. I would however strongly advice against relying on such compiler-specifics.

Comment: MSVC 19.37 will still happily compile code that calls a member function on `static_cast<Foo*>(nullptr)`, and not warn about it even with `/Wall /external:anglebrackets /external:W0`. The check will work as expected on this compiler. Clang will warn that `this` cannot be null, and disable the check. GCC will additionally warn that you are calling a member function on a null pointer, but also disable the check.